# Congruence relation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, congruence-relations

I did not have any number theory course, so can someone help me solve the following congruence relation for odd prime $p$ $$(-7)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$$
I want to find prime $p$ such that this is true.
I am not sure what operations are allowed but I thought I could do this:
$$(-7)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv -7 $$ where we can see that $\frac{p+1}{2}$ is an even power since primes are and so this does not have a solution. I am not sure if it is okay.

Comment: What do you want to solve? Do you mean find a prime $\;p\;$ such that the congruence is true, or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes I want to find such $p$ and actually I think this has no such solution

Answer (score 2):

By Euler's criterion,
$$(-1)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv\left(\frac{-7}p\right)\pmod p$$
where $\left(\frac{-7}p\right)$ is the Legendre symbol. By
quadratic reciprocity 
$$\left(\frac{-7}p\right)=\left(\frac p7\right)$$
and so your identity holds iff $p$ is a square modulo $7$
(as long as $p\ne7$).

Comment: Could you explain what it means to be a square modulo $7$?

Comment: For instance $11\equiv 2^2\pmod 7$. What is $(-7)^5$ modulo $11$? @mandella

Comment: it is 1 but I do not see what the wording 'square mod $7$' means